# Purpose of stacked cores

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, power-factor-correction

All the PFC that I have seen are equipped with a stacked core inductor. I do not understand what is the purpose of the stacked core.

[image]

Why do not just use a bigger core?

Comment: I myself have not got a clue...but I'd guess that it makes it easier/cheaper to manufacture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what each core experiences:

For one core, you have N turns and I current, for N*I magnetization.  And with \$l_e\$ and \$\mu_r\$ and all that, some inductance, flux, whatever...

If you repeat the same winding on another core and connect them in series, you get identical N*I, and..., and double the inductance in total, with identical current rating.

Makes sense, you've doubled the materials, so voltage is double and nothing else is different.

Stack two cores, with the same turns and current, and you get the same N*I, etc.  You've doubled the inductance, same current.

But wait!

In the separate-wound case, you had wire wrapping around all four sides of both cores.  In the stacked case, the two facing sides of the cores, *don't have wire between them!*  You've saved the length of two, whatever those radial side bits you want to call, of wire length.  More explicitly: the length of one turn, on one core, is on the order 2H + D - d, but for two cores stacked, it's 4H + D - d (H = height, D = outer diameter, d = inner diameter).  Assuming rectangular cross section and perfectly creased corners, and no wire diameter, but perhaps you get the idea (hence: "of the order", not exact!).

So this arrangement will have less wire resistance than the lone case, and cost slightly less because it's less copper of course.

Will the performance gain be as good as using a slightly larger core instead?  Hard to say.  But that might also be irrelevant: maybe you *can't fit* that big a core in your project, so you have to use smaller parts, or stacks.  It's an opportunity to adjust the aspect ratio of the components, something quite valuable when it comes to packing things into tight packages.  Maybe it's just economics: you're using that core elsewhere (in other components, or other products), so you have a good quantity discount going, and using a stack is cheaper than a single (that you'd be buying for just that one product).

Answer (score 3):

> *I do not understand what is the purpose of the stacked core.*

[Magnetics Inc](https://www.mag-inc.com/Products/Powder-Cores/Kool-Mu-HF-Cores?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8s3htrmv-QIVg-_tCh1TOAeuEAAYASAAEgKAhPD_BwE) (the company mentioned in the question) have got a great range of cores and, I have used several of them on jobs where a standard ferrite is just not "man-enough" for the magneto motive force (or ampere-turns) however, I have had to stack two cores to prevent excessive overheat due to excessive potential saturation levels.

I did this because although they have a wide range of cores, they did not have a core equivalent to two stacked cores. Additionally, [Magnetics Inc](https://www.mag-inc.com/Products/Powder-Cores/Kool-Mu-HF-Cores?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8s3htrmv-QIVg-_tCh1TOAeuEAAYASAAEgKAhPD_BwE) recommend this stacking method and, their on-line calculators provide for this option.

In short: not every option is covered in a particular range.